# Audio not working on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: sound, 20.10

So I downloaded Ubuntu 20.10 on my Chromebook using chrx. I booted it up and set it up, but when I opened Youtube, I couldn't hear anything. I went to Sound Settings and it said, that the current output device is Dummy Output, but no sound came out. It didn't recognise my headphones. I installed pavucontrol and in cofiguration it said that the built-in audio is off and everything else was unplugged and unavailable. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the kernel to "oem" series. Worked for me!